# How do I generate some sample solutions for an underdetermined system?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a system of 379 linear equations and 6325 unknowns. Does anyone know of a tool that can generate some (non-negative) solutions that satisfy this system? I know there are infinitely many, but it would be useful just to have a few for my purposes.

Comment: Are the equations all linear?

Comment: Yes, they are linear. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: Mathematica could probably handle this.

Comment: How do you know there is a non-negative solution? You could express the problem as a linear program.